# Defining additional infix operators in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to define additional infix operators in MATLAB?

Specifically, I'd like to define two infix operators `->` and `<->` (these symbols would be ideal, but it could be a single character if necessary), which call functions `implies` and `iff` in the same way that `&` calls `and` and `+` calls `plus`.

```
function z = implies(x, y)
    z = ~x|y;

function z = iff(x, y)
    z = x&y | ~x&~y;
```

I'm happy to overload `logical` if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to define new Operators in MATLAB as several threads like [this one](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/matlab/51236/How-to-Add-new-MATLAB-operator) suggest. However, if you'd like to *overload* an existing operator for you own *class*, here's MATLAB's [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/br02znk-1.html), though I'm sure you've already seen it.

Comment: I thought that was probably true - just hoping someone had a clever hack that might achieve it. Oh well :(

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`operator`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/operator.html) ? it is used to define new user-defined operator symbols or to delete them.

`operator(symb, f, T, prio)` defines a new operator symbol `symb` of type `T` with priority `prio`. The function `f` evaluates expressions using the new operator.

Given the operator symbol "++", say, with evaluating function `f`, the following expressions are built by the parser, depending on the type of the operator:

**Prefix**:     The input ++x results in f(x).

**Postfix**:    The input x++ results in f(x).

**Binary**:     The input x ++ y ++ z results in f(f(x, y), z).

**Nary**:       The input x ++ y ++ z results in f(x, y, z)).

see more at matlab's documentation in the link above.

Comment: That would be perfect if `operator` were part of core MATLAB, but it's part of Symbolic Toolbox.